# Cannot see debug output when running android virtual device

Tags: android

My app crashes on startup when using AVD, but I cannot see debug output.

[image]

Comment: at below click on android 
and from there click on logcat 
and try again please

Answer (score 0):

Debug output is in the Android tab. Anyway you can use `adb logcat`.

Answer (score 0):

You should watch adb logcat. It is below in Android Studio. When you get the error, don't press OK. You should open android studio and adb logcat. You can see the error what is it.